# TDI/Java-JavaScript System.openFileForOutput

Tags: java, javascript, tivoli

I'm developing a custom script in TDI. This script sends emails out based on a returned array.

As the emails are sent, I open up a file using the function `system.openFileForOutput`

Then I write the current email number, (1, 2, 3, etc).

Then I close the `system.openFileForOutput`.

So if I stop the script in the middle before it reaches the close statement, the file becomes empty and I don't know where the emails stopped.

I need some advice. How can I save the email # the script is at without losing the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close the file immediately after writing the content. Then open it whenever you want again close it.

--open new file and write

```
var file = "D:\\dump.txt";
var outfile = system.openFileForOutput(file);
outfile.newLine ();
outfile.write("Report")
outfile.newLine ();
outfile.close ();
```

--append content to the previously created file

```
var file = "D:\\dump.txt";
var outfile = system.openFileForAppend(file);
outfile.newLine ();
outfile.write("Report")
outfile.newLine ();
outfile.close ();
```

Also there are some google groups for TDI related doubt. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ibm.software.network.directory-integrator